# PHP array question

Tags: php, arrays, date

I was wondering how can I turn the following date into an array.

PHP code.

```
$current_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //current date
```

Comment: Elaborate. What should the components of the array be?

Comment: And just for curiosity's sake, what for?

Comment: to put the date in a loop to compare it to other dates

Comment: An array with a single date and a loop is the same as a single date and no loop. What's the goal?

Answer (score 2):

```
$current_date = array(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

Answer (score 1):

The built-in php function [`strptime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php) converts a date to an array.  See the linked documentation for details about the structure of the array it produces.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to get the components of the function return into an array.

```
// Method one

$current_date = array(date('Y'),date('m'),date('d'),date('H'),date('i'),date('s'));

// Method two

$current_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //current date
$exploded_current_date = explode(" ", $current_date);
$date = explode("-",$exploded_current_date[0]);
$time = explode(":",$exploded_current_date[1]);
$current_date = array_merge($date,$time);
```

Update:

```
// Method three

$current_date = getdate();

/*
Returns 
Array
(
    [seconds] => 40
    [minutes] => 58
    [hours]   => 21
    [mday]    => 17
    [wday]    => 2
    [mon]     => 6
    [year]    => 2003
    [yday]    => 167
    [weekday] => Tuesday
    [month]   => June
    [0]       => 1055901520
)
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example.

```
<?php
$format = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S';
$strf = strftime($format);
echo "$strf\n";
print_r(strptime($strf, $format));
?>
```